# Control of player buttons through extension chrome

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-chrome

I created extension: 
HTML code is lower:

```
<input id="play1" type="image" src="images/121.png"  type="button"  alt="Воспроизвести"/>
<input id="pause1" type="image" src="images/120.png"  type="button" alt="Пауза"/>
<input id="next1" type="image" src="images/122.png"   type="button" alt="След.трек"/>
```

I don't understand why javascript the id button = with "play1" after clicking doesn't work

Javascript this extension:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('play1').onclick = function(){



    }   
});
```

Code of control of player buttons:

```
<div id="ac_controls" class="fl_l">
    <div id="ac_play" class="fl_l"></div>
    <div class="next_prev fl_l">
      <div id="ac_prev" class="ctrl_wrap">
        <div class="prev ctrl"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="ac_next" class="ctrl_wrap">
        <div class="next ctrl"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you referencing jQuery in your html file? ex:
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` 
@pavel-bogr

Answer (score 0):

Then you will need to use `window.onload`. Your script will look something like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("play1").onclick = function() {
        alert("hello"); //for testing
    }
}
 </script>
```

`$(document).ready()` is a shortcut used in jQuery. Which you can make use of by adding the line below in your html.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Instead of aleret ('); I need to press the button in a tab: https:/test.com/audio/, a code of the button player

Comment: The Code of the button player above